# I'm having trouble understanding a proof of "the neighborhoods in R^n are open"

Tags: general-topology, proof-explanation

Lemma 137: "The neighborhoods in R^n are open."

[Proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dCiBx.png)

I can follow along and visualize the proof, but how does the final statement prove that each point within the neighborhood of x0 is an interior point, therefore making any neighborhood of R^n open?

Answer (score 0):

By definition: $x$ is an interior point of $S$ if there exists an open ball $B$ containing $x$ such that $B\subseteq S$.

The proof shows that given $x\in B_\varepsilon(x_0)$ one can construct the ball $B_{\varepsilon'}(x)$ around $x$ which is contained in $B_\varepsilon(x_0)$. That is, the set $B_\varepsilon(x_0) \sim S$ and $B_{\varepsilon'}(x)\sim B$ in the above definition.  Thus, the proof constructs the open ball $B$ around $x$ which is contained in $S$. This shows that $x$ is an interior point.

Comment: So because we've showed that any random point x is an interior point, we can assume that every point within the open ball B is an interior point?

Comment: We should be careful about wording here.  Indeed, this argument will work for any point I choose in the neighborhood. Thus, we have shown that every point x in a neighborhood is an interior point.  Since every point in a neighborhood is an interior point, we conclude that neighborhoods are open.  Note that we are not assuming anything here. We are proving that neighborhoods are open by showing each element of a neighborhood is an interior point.  You should remember that "S is open" is equivalent to "every element of S is an interior point."